# Adding text to a text box with a checkbox in Acrobat

Tags: forms, acrobat

I have a large form that checks the form results against the business logic & policy of a bank.

On the form is a place for comments.  I want to have the form automatically insert a comment in the text box if it is checked (removing it if it is unchecked), while still allowing the user to insert their own comments.

Is there a way to get this done?

Comment: Which comment does have precedence when the box is checked? the standard comment, or the user's comment, or should they be combined?

Comment: I think the system comment, however the user's comment needs to be retained through system comment changes.

Right now, I'm trying to store the user's comments in a hidden field and then parse them back out after the system comments get run.  I'm thinking about trying to set up the system comments as a function that checks all the business logic, then appends the users comments to the end/beginning.  What I can't figure beyond that is how to get the system comments to persist while the user is typing.